# two fixed responsive sidebars and a scrollable content div in the middle of responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to place 2 fixed Sidebars and a middle Content div so when i scroll the Content is scrolling. 
I could work with overflow scroll but then i have the scrollbar in the middle div which is a bit ugly.

For a better understanding here a Concept:
[image: CONCEPT]
So i already tried a bit but cant figured out a good stable solve.

Thanks for every help.

Comment: you need to create three columns. On the two that you dont want to scroll. You need to detect when the user scrolls and set position:fixed; on css

Comment: With Javascript/jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understood, you are looking for something like this [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/XXxvKv)

So the two sidebars are fixed:

```
.leftside {
   position: fixed;
   left: 10%;
   top: 150px;
   height: 300px;
   width: 10%;
   background: #ccc;
}
.rightside {
   position: fixed;
   right: 10%;
   top: 150px;
   height: 300px;
   width: 10%;
   background: #ccc;
}
```

For the scrollable one:

```
.scrollable {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
}
```

If you want the middle div to be fixed but the content inside of it move around, then you just need to add this to `.scrollable`:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

And you need to add this piece of jquery code as well to change the height of divs according to window resize:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".leftside, .rightside").height($(window).height()-100);
   $(".scrollable").height($(window).height()-40);
   $(window).resize(function() {
       $(".leftside, .rightside").height($(window).height()-100);
       $(".scrollable").height($(window).height()-40);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thats a awseome one :) but whats when you scroll out ? then i saw that the divs are moving oO.

Comment: if you are talking about the outer scrollbar, that's because the height of the window. try the example in debug mode in a separate page. You will see the outermost scrollbar gone

Comment: no i mean the space between the content div and the sidebars on big screens and or that the sidebars going smaller when you zoom in. Idk if that would be a problem

Comment: I really don't know what you are looking for. But I have tried something new. Check out the pen  http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/XXxvKv

Comment: Not what iam searching :) I want that when you zoom that the sidebar are dont going smaller in width. Means that there is same 200px at everytime also when you zoom. It tried to add them or pin them at the content div too but haha not working ofc. Cause when you zoom atm the space of the sidebars are going really small

Comment: what do you mean by "zooming"? are you talking about resizing the window?  I just modified something else. Check out the pen.

Comment: Yeah when you zoom the Browser Windows. And yeaht that is what i searched! Awesome Job dude :D!

Comment: So please do not say "zoom", zooming is different and nobody can creates responsive design for that. It is "resizing" which designers create responsive design.

Comment: Okey :) sry i will remember for next time!

Comment: No problem my friend. Please upvote my answer, I deserve it ;)

Comment: Hey i will fast as i can iam to nooby atm to give u a upvote :) And yes you do xD!